# Multiple read access to one Kinect v2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, libfreenect2

I want to use **one** Kinect v2 camera for **multiple** applications on **one** computer. If I try to to get access with a second application both applications crashes. Right now I am using libfreenect2.

Is it somehow possbile to do that? Are the pictures somewhere buffered where I could maybe copy them or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: You could write a single application that distributes the camera data to your two applications.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The problem is that one app is a open source software, the code is quiet complex, so thats probably not an option.